# Set an async trigger for an Update Panel with a GridView asp:ButtonField

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

What is correct sytnax for setting an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` for an `UpdatePanel` with an `asp:ButtonField` from an `GridView` control?

I need to set an 'AsyncPostBackTrigger' for each asp:ButtonField in my `GridView`

Here is my source code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">       
            <Columns>        
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Button1" SelectText="Click Me!" />        
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Button2" SelectText="No Click Me!" />    
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Update**

I need to keep the `UpdateMode` and `ChildrenAsTriggers` attributes set to true because the I have other button contained within the `UpdatePanel` that do not refresh the `UpdatePanel` control

Answer (score 0):

The ChildrenAsTriggers property being set to true will cause any control that causes a postback within the update panel to cause it to refresh.  You would only need to use the triggers element if you had a control outside of the update panel you wished to use to trigger the refresh of that update panel.  You don't even need the triggers element in this instance.

Comment: see comment addressed to Josh

Answer (score 0):

Everything that Lance Harper mentioned is true, but you also need to remove the following attribute:

```
UpdateMode="Conditional"
```

Having that attribute in place will prevent the automatic wire-up of your client side events. Essentially you are telling ASP.Net that you are going to do this yourself.

Comment: I want to keep the conditional attribute set to true because I have buttons within the panel that do not cause the UpdatePanel to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a template field instead of a command field, and forcibly update (UpdatePanel.Update()) the panel when the command button is clicked?

Comment: I had the wrong code sample.  It should be an asp:ButtonField column instead of asp:CommandField column.  I updated my code sample

Comment: I think my suggestion would still work.  Use a Template field, execute the command when the button is pressed, then update the panel.